# Cross-Platform > Class Library (Xamarin.Forms) using VS2017 will not create Droid and iOS projects

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have .Net 4.5.1 (I am not trying to target .NetStandard) and Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247 and latest VS2017 15.2 (26430.15). I create a new project using Cross-Platform > Class Library (Xamarin.Forms) and do not get the 2 projects for (.Droid and .iOS). Been all over Google but come up empty handed.

I am trying to follow one of the many 'getting started with Xamarin' videos/course and cannot get to first base. OK so they are using VS2015 but I have not read anywhere that VS2017 is a problem.

What do I need to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new Class Library project, you will only get a PCL project. If you want to create a solution with PCL, iOS UI and Android UI project, create using Cross-Platform > Cross Platform App (Xamarin) template. Then from there you can see dialog to select Native or Xamarin.Forms template.
[image]

Comment: lowleetak Thank you so much.
Obviously being a newbie in Xamarin I know zero. I guess what confused me was that my understanding is that X.Forms is specifically designed for multiple GUIs. But of course I am probably wrong. I ticked the up-vote but I have too few credits.